# inserting in a vector of vector string from vector of vector pair<int,string>

Tags: c++

```
vector<vector<pair<int,string>>> v(mxfreq+1);
  for(it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
  {
   v[it->second.second].push_back(make_pair(it->second.first,it->first));

  }
  vector<vector<string>> v1;
  for(int i=mxfreq;i>=0;i--)
  {
    string t=to_string(i);
    if(v[i].size()>1)
    {
      sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    }
    for(int j=0;j<v[i].size();j++)
    {
      v1.push_back(v[i][j].second);
      v1.push_back(t);
    }
  }
//cout<<v[0][0].first<<endl;
  return v1;
```

here i am trying to insert it into a vector of vector string from vector of vector pair<int,string> but i am getting error **v1.push_back(v[i][j].second);**
here the **mxfreq** we can assume to be a  integer >0

Comment: I would first make sure that the destination vectors had the correct size. Then for each sub-vector use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to, well, *transform* each `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` into a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  i only want the string part to be appended in the second vector v1

Comment: That would be purpose of the `std::transform` call. Or simply just a nested [ranged-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to ensure both the size and do the copying? That would be even simpler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you please tell with one example

Comment: What error are you actually getting? Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Comment: @KarlKnechtel   error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::push_back(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'|

Comment: Well, yes. You can't add a string to a vector of (vectors of strings), because the thing you put into that is a vector of strings, not a single string. Look at the line of code again: what do you expect `v[i][j].second` to be? A string, right? Where do you want that to get added? Surely not directly to `v1`, but instead to one of the vectors inside v1?

Comment: Or maybe - putting my wild guessing hat on - `t` is a vector of strings, and you wanted to add the string there, and then append `t` to `v1`? Please do not make other people put on their wild guessing hats. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), formatted as code.

Comment: ...But only after you first [try to fix the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), perhaps following a guide [like this one](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the "simple" solution using [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) nested inside each other, it could be done something like:

```
// Make sure the destination vector have enough memory allocated
v1.reserve(v.size());

for (auto const& v_pairs : v)
{
    // Create a temporary vector for the string
    std::vector<std::string> v_strings;

    // And make sure it have enough memory allocated
    v_strings.reserve(v_pairs.size());

    // Copy the string from each pair into the string vector
    for (auto const& pair : v_pairs)
    {
        v_strings.emplace_back(pair.second);
    }

    // And move the string vector into the destination vector
    v1.emplace_back(std::move(v_strings));
}
```

Comment: There are any number of ways to solve the problem, including OP's basic approach. This does not help OP to debug or figure out what is going on. The question should probably just be closed; my best guesses as to what went wrong all boil down to typos.